# Can lttng capture any user defined trace points?

Tags: qemu, libvirt, lttng

I try to probe qemu network operation. So, I create one new trace point inside net/net.c:qemu_deliver_packet(). The TP successfully installed (# lttng list -u).  However the TP didn't showed up when I run the lttng session.  The thing is, the same trace point showed up when I use printf().
Why is that? is it because I need to configure something for libvirt (i use libvirt)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the tracepoint, with `lttng enable-event -u [event name]` (or `-a`)?

Having a tracepoint appear in `lttng list -u` means it's registered and available, but you need to enable it in the trace session to have it generate trace events.

Comment: Yes I did.  I think it is down to libvirt, because when I ran Qemu manually (without virsh), then I can capture that TP. Now I want to know how to enable it when using libvirt. Should I change something within 'libvirtd.cfg'?

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that libvirt launches qemu via a fork()? In this case, you might have to use liblttng-ust-fork library. Basically `LD_PRELOAD=liblttng-ust-fork.so [appname]`. See [this section](http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-using-lttng-ust-with-daemons) of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you must had user "libvirt-qemu" to "tracing" group. When user is not part of tracing group he can read/write the trace for Lttng. See http://linuxmogeb.blogspot.ca/2016/02/trace-qemu-with-lttng-ust-under-libvirt.html